# jQuery Boilerplate Pattern - local variables vs object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, jquery-boilerplate

I just started using jQuery boilerplate and i am unsure about the use of local variables vs object properties. When a function on the prototype (`Plugin.prototype`) has makes use of values that do not need to be shared with rest of the functions should i use `var`? Also is it OK to assign object properties in the functions themselves or should all values be store in the constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: You should always declare your variables in the lowest scope possible. It's also absolutely fine to assign object properties anywhere you require

Comment: if you don't use `var` (or `let`,`const`), your variable will be created in  global scope

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That makes sense, since the constructor will load it's properties with each instance, it would be waste to load anything that is not shared. So in the case of a local value `var` (or `let`) is fine in a prototype function?